# Как преобразовать мак адрес?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ip, ifconfig, mac-address

Захожу в терминал, набираю `ifconfig`. На выходи имею информацию по адаптерам в системе. Мне надо получить мак-адрес. В выводе от `ipconfig` я вижу представление вида `00:1e:ec...`, а мне надо 10-чное представление. Как мне его получить?

Comment: а зачем вам десятичное представление мак-адреса, если не секрет ?) так-то скрипт написать можно по разбору ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вроде так

```
a=`ifconfig eth0|grep HW |awk '{print $5}'|tr -d ':'`; echo $((0x$a))
```